# Extract single file from tar without taking its directories with it

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, tar

I'm currently using this command

```
    tar -zxvf foo.tgz -C /root/dir1/ dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file
```

to extract my specific file from a tar archive to a given directory, dir1. As is, I end up with `root/dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4/dir5/file` but what I am after is `root/dir1/file`. This is important because I have 1000 of these files and I don't want to have to open all the individual directories to get to them. Does anyone know how to extract just the file?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU tar, you can use `--strip-components` to remove a specific number of directory levels before the filename. Otherwise, use `-O` and redirect the output into the desired file.

Comment: Thanks! `--strip-components` works in regular tar too

Comment: @user1792403: [No, it doesn't.](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xcu/tar.html)

Comment: oh, then i must be in GNU tar without realising? i haven't loaded gnu though

Comment: @user1792403: If you're running Linux, you're using GNU tools.